# Xcode Server Bots API: Updating a bot with PATCH request

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, httprequest, xcode-server, xcode-bots

I would like to edit my Xcode bot through the Xcode Server API by sending the [blueprint](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/XcodeServerAPIReference/Blueprint.html) through PATCH.

However, when I send my PATCH request, Xcode Server replies back an unchanged json of my old blueprint.

My request is `curl -X PATCH -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"my\": \"json\"}" https://<username>:<password>@<my_domain>:20343/api/bots/<bot_id>`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two missing parameters that will cause the following problems:

- Missing `xcsclientversion`: server will return 400 Bad Request.
- Missing `overwriteBlueprint=true`: server will not change the blueprint.

Your final request should look like the following:

`curl -X PATCH -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "x-xcsclientversion: 18" -d "{\"json goes\": \"here\"}" https://<username>:<password>@<domain>:20343/api/bots/<_id>?overwriteBlueprint=true`

Source: radar and Developer Relations (thanks!)